# Keyboard and Mousepad completely not working 18.04 (Working in Windows)

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, laptop, 18.04

I have an Asus X541U laptop, dual booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Currently writing this from Windows 10. You'll understand why later.

#### **Preliminary Information:**

I just installed Ubuntu yesterday. During the installation, I had to disable secure boot, in order to download third-party software and drivers. Right after the install, I had the classic "shutdown suspended indefinitely" problem. Fixed it with with a kernel upgrade to `4.17-rc5` (from `4.15`). Everything was now doing fine, and I went to bed after shutting down successfully.

#### **The current problem:**

Today when I booted for the first time, I chose to boot to Ubuntu. At the login screen, to my big surprise, I discovered that my keyboard wasn't working, at all. I luckily have a mouse, because I also found out my mousepad was completely useless as well. I used the virtual keyboard that comes with Ubuntu, and with that, I could get past the login page, but even after many solution attempts and reboots, the whole base (keyboard, mousepad) of my laptop doesn't work.

#### **What I've tried so far (unsuccessful):**

I searched the whole universe (ok maybe not) for solutions and found a couple that could potentially fix my problem:

- I could try reinstalling the X.org drivers (`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`). Didn't work
- Some people suggested going in the system settings and deactivate or activate some stuff. Strange thing that I saw: There is no settings option for my keyboard nor for my mousepad. As a matter of fact, they don't even appear in the settings. It's like they are completely gone, disconnected!
- Other people said that it's more than likely a hardware/BIOS problem. I think it can't be that because when I boot and work on Windows, everything works absolutely fine!
- Some were also saying that I could try logging in with Ubuntu on Wayland, instead of the default. It's apparently a "newer" technology or something, that could fix my problem. Nope, it didn't.

If ever anybody needs some specs or additional information, I can gladly supply it. It will be hard using the virtual keyboard to type everything in Ubuntu, but I have to do what it takes. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you solved it? ... I'm facing same issue in x.org session but everything working fine with wayland except screen shearing .

Comment: @Ahmed I just ended up reinstalling it and the problem disappeared. It probably means I screwed it up myself somehow, but I'm sorry I can't help you too.